# WYSIWYG links and MVC routes working together

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, href, relative-path

I have a url http://domain.com/shopname and the contents of this page has links created from a CMS, one of which is `p/101/productname`.

All fine however I was hopeful the url would be evaluated to http://domain.com/shopname/p/101/productname when the page renders, but this isnt the case and the browser reads the link as http://domain.com/p/101/productname.

This can be resolved if the initial page where the url is constructed from is http://domain.com/shopname/ rather than http://domain.com/shopname. Notice the trailing slash. This isnt something I can rely on so im looking for a solution.

It is an ASP.NET MVC application and the route is defined using the following template:

`"{shopName}/p/{productId}/{SeoName}"`

An obvious solution is to add a route name parameter within the WYSIWYG and rewrite the url using a helper in the view or when the view model is transformed from the domain model within the controller. However this is not ideal and would be keen to learn if there was an obvious solution that im missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of non-activity on this question I have decided to use a token within the WYSIWYG and replace it with the desired value when my View Model is transformed.